# React cannot read an object inside array (state)

Tags: reactjs

Relatively new to React, wrote a few components before (successfully), but this is the first time I'm getting something started from scratch. I use Rails with Cassandra to provide JSON responses, and everything on the back end side is working fine.

My data `this.state.data` looks like this:

```
0 {id: {n: 2.1751612473052575e+38}, email: "123@zeba.me", high_score: 73, shoe_size: 10.5, updated_at: "2018-11-06T01:23:36.611-08:00"}
1 {id: {n: 2.8024982600468778e+38}, email: "123@sotkamonlukio.fi", high_score: 13, shoe_size: 7.5, updated_at: "2018-11-06T01:24:55.791-08:00"}
2 {id: {n: 2.4227336868283995e+38}, email: "123@icloud.com", high_score: 99, shoe_size: 10.5, updated_at: "2018-11-06T01:24:07.858-08:00"}
```

And doing `this.state.data[1]` obviously returns

```
{id: {n: 2.8024982600468778e+38}, email: "123@sotkamonlukio.fi", high_score: 13, shoe_size: 7.5, updated_at: "2018-11-06T01:24:55.791-08:00"}
```

However, `this.state.data[1].email` throws this

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data[1].email')
```

What can I do to access email and the rest of the data?

---

full component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Table extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="table">
        <h1>LOL</h1>
        <p>{this.state.data[1].email}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: please add all the component code . you probably didn't initialised the state and render the component

Comment: @NaorTedgi sure, updated the post.

Comment: yap it is  what I suspect. check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when your component starts the rendering, the `this.state.data[1].email` wasn't loaded already. Just check if the data was already loaded, like below:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.data.length > 0)
        return(
             <div className="table">
                <h1>LOL</h1>
                <p>{this.state.data[1].email}</p>
             </div>
        )
    else return <div/>
}
```

The other possible solution is to use the `map` function. It will only render something when the array it's filled. The code is below:

```
render(){
    return(
         <div className="table">
            <h1>LOL</h1>
            { this.state.data.map(user => <p>{user.email}</p>) }
         </div>
    )
}
```

For each user in the `data` array, the component will render a tag `<p>` with the email. When there's nothing in the array, the component will render nothing.

Comment: Is there a way to only render the component if data is fully loaded without flooding the code with an extra if statement? I have never seen such construction in production-ready code.

Comment: The `if` is already only rendering the component if the data is fully loaded. But, I'll add a possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

its a common error the request didn't complete before the render method is called just add an if statement

```js
  render () {
    const { data } = this.state
    return (
      <div className='table'>
        <h1>LOL</h1>
        {data.length > 0 && <p>{data[1].email}</p>}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid such an if statement? It seems to be complicating the code for no reason.

Comment: you always have to return value from the render method. there is all kind of ways to avoid it both its depends on your app component hierarchy

Comment: i think this is the same issue  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808247/how-to-do-render-only-after-http-request-completed-in-reactjs see Appunni M answer

Comment: @PeterChudinov i Update to something more elegant

Answer (score 0):

This.state.data initially set to an empty array. So when your component first time renders it will be an empty array.

In componentDidMount you are making an api call and assigning api response to the state data. So this method gets called after first render

The reason you get that issue because you are accessing 1st index from this.state.data array which is obviously an empty array at the time of first render. So what you have to do is

Change

```
   <p>{this.state.data[1].email}</p>
```

To

```
    <p>{this.state.data.length > 0 && this.state.data[1].email}</p>
```

Or do iterate the array and render p elements

```
   {this.state.data.length > 0 && this.state.data.map(d => (  
            <p key={d.id}>d.email}</p>
   )}
```

If you don’t have unique id per object in array then use index as key